# How to package dependencies with snapshots for Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I tried to package dependencies for Apache IoTDB V1.1.0 locally, I received an error: `Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.iotdb:iotdb-consensus:jar:1.1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.ratis:ratis-server:jar:2.4.2-ebba77d-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.ratis:ratis-common:jar:2.4.2-ebba77d-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.ratis:ratis-grpc:jar:2.4.2-ebba77d-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.ratis:ratis-server:jar:2.4.2-ebba77d-SNAPSHOT`.
There is snapshots in this dependency, I wonder how can I successfully package it?